# How to load a .fsx file in mono (OS X), and use the internal types\functions?

Tags: f#, mono, f#-interactive

I installed mono on OS X via `brew install mono`, and F# v. 4.01 is loaded when I run `fsharpi` in the terminal.

I have a `.fsx` file that defines some types and functions. I wish to use them interactively in `fsi` (an alias for `fsharpi`). For this purpose, I fire up `fsi` and run `#load "pc.fsx;;"` - the file is loaded and compiled, and I see all of the type definitions and function types, under a generic namespace. For some reason, the REPL doesn't recognize the custom types (so I can't use the type constructors) and functions, so I get error FS0039: `The value or constructor '<insert type or function name>' is not defined`. How can I overcome this?

EDIT:
The file is named `Temp.fsx` and the contents are wrapped with a module named `Temp`.

File content:

```
module Temp =

  open System

  /// Type that represents Success/Failure in parsing
  type Result<'a> =
      | Success of 'a
      | Failure of string

  /// Type that wraps a parsing function
  type Parser<'T> = Parser of (string -> Result<'T * string>)

  /// Parse a single character
  let pchar charToMatch =
      // define a nested inner function
      let innerFn str =
          if String.IsNullOrEmpty(str) then
              Failure "No more input"
          else
              let first = str.[0]
          if first = charToMatch then
                  let remaining = str.[1..]
              Success (charToMatch,remaining)
          else
              let msg = sprintf "Expecting '%c'. Got '%c'" charToMatch first
              Failure msg
  // return the "wrapped" inner function
      Parser innerFn

  /// Run a parser with some input
  let run parser input =
      // unwrap parser to get inner function
      let (Parser innerFn) = parser
      // call inner function with input
      innerFn input
```

Compilation output from `fsi`:

```
$ fsi

F# Interactive for F# 4.1
Freely distributed under the Apache 2.0 Open Source License

For help type #help;;

> #load "Temp.fsx";;
[Loading /Users/asaf/programming/PCfs/Temp.fsx]

namespace FSI_0002
  module Temp = begin
    type Result<'a> =
      | Success of 'a
      | Failure of string
    type Parser<'T> = | Parser of (string -> Result<'T * string>)
    val pchar : charToMatch:char -> Parser<char>
    val run : parser:Parser<'a> -> input:string -> Result<'a * string>
  end
```

Comment: What do you mean by custom types? Can you show a more concrete example of how the types are defined in the file and how they are called. FSI does put the types under a custom namespace. Is it inside some module/namespace? What if you #load or #r an .fs file?

Comment: type Result<'a> =
    | Success of 'a
    | Failure of string

The code isn't inside a module or namespace.

Comment: Put into a module at least. I haven't tested other workarounds.

Comment: @s952163 Wrapping the file in a module actually helps, but it gets ugly: I name the module `Temp`, and when I wish to use an internal function or type constructor, I have to reference them like this: `Temp.Temp.Success 1`, which is just fugly. Any way around this?

Comment: Fugly? :D maybe bizarre... I am not sure and I cant test it right now...but are you saying that the file is named Temp and the contents are inside a module called Temp? it would be helpful to post a complete file sample including the fsi output when you load it. btw, you can decorate the module with the Autoopen attribute or some such thing but I am not sure how relevant that is...

Comment: Yes, the file is named `Temp.fsx` and the module inside of it is named `Temp`. The only way to reference the internals is via `Temp.Temp`. I'll add the code and output as an edit to the question.

Comment: this happens because you indented the top level module. Please look at the file format in my or @krontogiannis's example. If you add Autopen on the top you will directly be able to access the contents, if you leave the Autopen off, then you will need to prefix with the module name, if you indent, you will need to prefix with Filename.Modulename. If you don't have a module declaration you will prefix with Filename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just declare at the top of your `fsx` an `AutoOpen` module with the same name and you are good to go:

```
[<AutoOpen>]
module Temp

open System

/// Type that represents Success/Failure in parsing
type Result<'a> =
    | Success of 'a
    | Failure of string

/// Type that wraps a parsing function
type Parser<'T> = Parser of (string -> Result<'T * string>)

/// Parse a single character
let pchar charToMatch =
    // define a nested inner function
    let innerFn str =
        if String.IsNullOrEmpty(str) then
            Failure "No more input"
        else
            let first = str.[0]
            if first = charToMatch then
                let remaining = str.[1..]
                Success (charToMatch,remaining)
            else
                let msg = sprintf "Expecting '%c'. Got '%c'" charToMatch first
                Failure msg
    // return the "wrapped" inner function
    Parser innerFn

/// Run a parser with some input
let run parser input =
    // unwrap parser to get inner function
    let (Parser innerFn) = parser
    // call inner function with input
    innerFn input
```

Load in fsi:

```
» fsharpi

F# Interactive for F# 4.1
Freely distributed under the Apache 2.0 Open Source License

For help type #help;;

> #load "Temp.fsx";;
[Loading /Users/kostas/workspace/fsharp/Temp.fsx]

namespace FSI_0002
type Result<'a> =
    | Success of 'a
    | Failure of string
type Parser<'T> = | Parser of (string -> Result<'T * string>)
val pchar : charToMatch:char -> Parser<char>
val run : parser:Parser<'a> -> input:string -> Result<'a * string>

> run (pchar 'f') "foo";;
val it : Result<char * string> = Success ('f', "oo")
> Failure "42";;
val it : Result<'a> = Failure "42"
>
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it in an .fsx file per se, but I assume it should work. You can put it into an .fs file, let's say File1.fs and put a module declaration on top, and do `#load "File1.fs"`

Then in FSI you can refer xxy as `File1.xxy;;`, and you can create it as `File1.B "jds";;`.

```
module File1

type A =
    | B of string
    | C of int

let xxy = B "sds"
```

Usually you just send the code from the editor to FSI directly and work in the editor so you don't have this problem...

**For example**

Based on your type I was able to get:

```
File1.Failure "blah";;
val it : File1.Result<'a> = Failure "blah"
```

**Edit for fsx file example:**

Here are some of the variations mentioned in my comment. The filename is `Script11.fsx`, the module's name is `Temp` (when specified). It is just loaded into a fsi session running inside PowerShell: `#load @"Script11.fsx";;`

1) No modulename declaration. Prefix with filename.

```
open System
type A =
    | B of string
    | C of int

let xxy = B "sds"

//> Script11.xxy;;
//val it : Script11.A = B "sds"
//>
```

2) Modulename declaration. Not indented. Prefix with modulename.

```
module Temp
open System

type A =
    | B of string
    | C of int

let xxy = B "sds"

//> Temp.xxy;;
//val it : Temp.A = B "sds"
//>
```

3) Indented modulename (your version), with an *equal sign, which will place the module inside the file name space*. You can see this as it starts with `module Temp = begin`. Prefix with filename and modulename.

```
module Temp =
    open System

    type A =
        | B of string
        | C of int

    let xxy = B "sds"

//> Script11.Temp.xxy;;
//val it : Script11.Temp.A = B "sds"
//>
```

4) Now for the difference between Autoopen or not:

```
//[<AutoOpen>]
module Temp =
    open System

    type A =
        | B of string
        | C of int

    let xxy = B "sds"
```

If you comment out `Autoopen` you will need refer to the contents of your module by prefixing it with the modulename.

```
open Script11;;
Temp.xxy;;
//val it : Temp.A = B "sds"
```

If you use `Autopen` then you still need to open the Filename but you can directly access the things inside your module.

```
> open Script11;;
> xxy;;
//val it : A = B "sds"
```

To cut the long story short, generally you shouldn't need the Autoopen if you have a top level declaration, and if you don't indent and create extra namespace you can directly access the contents. Otherwise you are creating a local module and obviously then you have to use the path. See [Modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/modules).

Comment: Sending the file to `fsi` is handy when I write the file in order to check for code correctness, but the end result is for an external user to load the `.fsx` file in a terminal (via `fsi`) and apply a single function on some input file in order to process it.

Comment: @asafc yes, of course I use fsx files too, they are convenient as a scratchpad because they are not compiled by fsc. you can load an .fs file too with a module declaration. unfortunatelyni do not have mono but later will test the fsx version. but basically this is loaded into fsi, ie I am not sending it from the edito.

Comment: thank you for the revised answer, it is much clearer and helped me understand all these awkward combinations that I tested myself, without really understanding what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

When you `#load` an `.fsx` file in F# interactive, all definitions in that file end up in a module named after the file, capitalized. So, for example, if you `#load "pc.fsx"`, then all your definitions will end up in a module named `Pc`.

```
#load "pc.fsx"

let r = Pc.Success "value"
```

Comment: This doesn't work as described. Loading the `.fsx` file doesn't result in a module with the filename capitalized. Again, I'm using mono in OS X - maybe the behavior of `fsi` is different in Windows?